# Story Identification: About a man who grew up alone on Mercury as a boy

Tags: story-identification

I read this book when I was a teenager, I think it was one of a series.  All I can remember is that the main character grew up alone on Mercury when all of the settlers were killed.  Ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: More information about the author, the edition, the approximate year of publishing would be very helpful Judy. Enjoy your stay at Scifi&Fantasy SE. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Might that be one of the [Eric John Stark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_John_Stark) stories by Leigh Brackett?  Stark was raised by Mercurians after his parents died in a mining accident.

> Stark was born on Mercury. His parents were employees of the mineral
>   extraction company Mercury Metals and Mining. After his parents died
>   in a cave-in caused by a quake, Stark was adopted by a tribe of
>   Mercurian aborigines who are described as hairy and possessing
>   snouts. They gave him the name N'Chaka, meaning "the man without a
>   tribe". He believed himself to be one of them, rather than a human,
>   and endured their rigorous way of life in the Mercurian Twilight Belt,
>   surviving by hunting rock-lizards.